# send push notification using device_token

Tags: python, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to send every user a push notification. I want to do this with a device_token.
I am storing the device_tokens in Firebase Cloud Firestore.

```
func storeDeviceTokenFromUserInFirestore(device_token: Data) {

    
    let device_tokenToString = device_token.hexString
    print("device_tokenToString", device_tokenToString)
    
    DATABASE_FIRESTORE.collection("device_token_from_user").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                var value = document.data().values.description
                value = String(value.dropFirst())
                value = String(value.dropLast())
                if device_tokenToString == value {
                    return
                } else {
                    var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
                    ref = self.DATABASE_FIRESTORE.collection("device_token_from_user").addDocument(data: ["device_token" : device_tokenToString
                    ]) { err in
                        if let err = err {
                            print("Error adding document: \(err)")
                        } else {
                            print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         } 
      } 
    }
```

with a Python script I want to send a push notification to every user.

```
    for token in tokens:
    
        serverToken = 'myServerToken'
        deviceToken = token
    
        headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'key=' + serverToken,
            }
    
        body = {
                'notification': {'title': 'Sending push form python script',
                                    'body': 'New Message'
                                    },
                'to':
                    deviceToken,
                'priority': 'high',
                #   'data': dataPayLoad,
                }
        response = requests.post("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",headers = headers, data=json.dumps(body))
        print(response.status_code)
    
        print(response.json())
```

After executing this code, I not receiving a push notification. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: Sorry, my fault.

Comment: Is the notification push already working on a testing env? 
So we can narrow down the problem to the Firebase or the to the part of your code where the problem relies.
I suggest to edit the tags for the question too.

Comment: I solved the problem just right now. I saved the fcm token in Firestore instead of the device token.